# Evitar modo de compatibilidade do Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Estou dando manutenção num código antigo em c#.

O programa era instalado em Windows 7 na época em que foi criado, agora com Windows 10 é necessário executar com o modo de compatibilidade para funcionar.

Compilando com um .Net mais atual, não seria mais necessário executar como compatibilidade?

Ou teria que fazer algo a mais?

Answer (score 0):

Compila com um framework mais atual que corrigirá o problema, lembrando que ao mudar o framework pode deixar de funcionar algumas funções do código, faça backup antes e depois faça o teste, caso aconteça algum erro, (se não forem muitos) vale a pena corrigi-los.